# How to Install go-ethereum on Redhat Linux?

Tags: go-ethereum

I would like to install go-ethereum on Redhat Linux 6.X. I have visited https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum link but it does not show installation steps for Redhat Linux 6.X.

Please guide me details steps to setup go-ethereum on RHEL machine.

Is it it possible to setup without using vargrant / docker / build go src?

Comment: any insight on the solution shared?

Comment: very helpful. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to build it yourself, as i know there is no geth binaries for REDHAT based systems.
**Firstly** you need to have go and gcc :

```
sudo dnf install golang
dnf install automake make gcc gcc-c++ git gmp-devel kernel-devel
```

**secondly** :

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git
cd go-ethereum
make geth
```

if you get an error about glibc, install it as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616650/how-to-upgrade-glibc-from-version-2-12-to-2-14-on-centos).